# Troubles with using memcpy with mmap

Tags: c, linux

Trying to copy a file using these functions, everything goes fine until program hits the memcpy function which gives a bus error and terminates the process.

```
void copy_mmap(char* in, char* out){

int input_fd, output_fd;

input_fd = open (in, O_RDONLY);
if (input_fd == -1) {
        printf("Error opening input file.\n");
        exit(2);
}

output_fd = open(out, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR);
if(output_fd == -1){
    printf("Error opening output file.\n");
    exit(3);
}

struct stat st;
fstat(input_fd, &st);

char* target;
target=mmap(0, st.st_size+1, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, input_fd, 0);
if (target==(void*) -1){
    printf("Error mapping target with errno: %d.\n", errno);
    exit(6);
}


char* destination;
destination=mmap(0, st.st_size+1, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, output_fd, 0);
if (destination==(void*) -1){
    printf("Error mapping destination with errno: %d.\n", errno);
    exit(5);
}

memcpy(destination, target, st.st_size);
munmap(destination, st.st_size);



}
```

Failed to figure out what is wrong, as "Bus Error" isn't a descriptive error message and there isn't any much material on the internet regarding this problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you create the destination file as a new file, its size is 0 bytes. `memcpy` crashes because it tries to write data beyond the end of the file.

You can make this work by pre-sizing the destination file to the size of the source file (using `ftruncate()`) before you `mmap()` it.

Also, you should pass `st.st_size` as the second argument to `mmap`, not `st.st_size+1`. `st.st_size+1` tries to map a range that is larger than the size of the file, which is invalid.

Comment: Also if you extremely care for speed and don't mind writing OS specific code you could use the different `sendfile` variants that exists on Unix(-like) operating systems. This file does the whole copy operating in kernel space (no data gets copied back and forth to user space): http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sendfile&sektion=2 https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sendfile.2.html

Answer (score 1):

you could also lseek to off_t fileposition= lseek(output_fd, st.st_size-1, SEEK_SET) and write an empty character to output_fd.

Comment: Yes! Before mmap() use: lseek( d, size - 1, SEEK_SET ); write( d, &d , 1 );  
where d is your file descriptor (get it with open() function).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to use memmove? Are you not reading and writing from the same memory/file/device location? Memcpy fails in such situations.

Comment: `memcpy()` only has problems (that can be solved by using `memmove()`) if the source and destination arrays overlap. Since the source and destination are allocated by two separate successfull calls to `mmap()` with a null pointer as the first argument, they can't overlap.

Comment: @KeithThompson I doubt there's any memory allocated through mmap, it only creates a mapping to the specified place. Had these been the same files, I still believe memmove could have helped.

Comment: @DariuszWawer: Whether you call it allocation or not, it makes a range of (virtual) memory addresses available to the program. The two ranges made available by the two calls to `mmap()` cannot overlap (if `mmap()` isn't broken), so `memmove() won't help. Further evidence: the OP tried it and it didn't help, but Celada's answer worked.