# memcpy with OpenCV: Why does a video frame require ftruncate, but an image does not?

Tags: c++, opencv

## Edit

The results observed by the user changed after some time.  The problem seems to have disappeared.  This question should be considered closed, but I won't delete it.

## Original question:

I ran into a peculiar problem while storing an `OpenCV` `Mat` into memory with `memcpy`.

### MWE

```
/* 
 * MWE of mmap + memcpy + opencv mat
 */


// Includes
#include <fcntl.h>                          // for open, O_CREAT, O_RDWR
#include <pthread.h>                        // for pthread_mutex_init, pthre...
#include <stdlib.h>                         // for NULL
#include <string>                           // for strings
using std::string;
#include <sys/mman.h>                       // for MAP_ANONYMOUS, MAP_SHARED
#include <unistd.h>                         // for ftruncate

#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Mat frame;

//     VideoCapture cap(argv[1]);
//     cap >> frame;
    frame = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    const size_t shmem_size = frame.total() * frame.elemSize();

    std::cout << "frame dimensions: " << frame.size().width << " x " << frame.size().height << " x " << frame.elemSize() << " = " << shmem_size << std::endl;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    int frame_fd = open("/tmp/file", O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP);
    std::cout << "frame_fd: " << frame_fd << std::endl;

//     int junk = ftruncate(frame_fd, shmem_size);

    unsigned char *buf = static_cast <unsigned char*>(mmap(NULL, shmem_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, frame_fd, 0));
    std::cout << "buf size: " << sizeof(*buf) << std::endl;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    std::cout << "mutex locked" << std::endl;

    memcpy(buf, frame.ptr(), shmem_size);
    std::cout << "memcpy'd" << std::endl;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    std::cout << "first: " << sizeof(*buf) << std::endl;
    Mat resized = cv::Mat(Size(frame.size().width, frame.size().height), 16, buf, frame.elemSize() * frame.size().width);
    imshow("test", resized);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

In addition to the MWE, I have a short test video in `MP4` format and a single frame from the video in the `png` format.

### Observations

#### Case 1

Compiling and running the code from the MWE with a test `png` file, I get the following output before seeing the image pop up:

```
g++ test.cpp -Wall -g -O3 -L/opt/vc/lib/ -lpthread `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -I/opt/vc/include/ -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux -o frame_extractor
frame dimensions: 1920 x 1080 x 3 = 6220800
frame_fd: 3
buf size: 1
mutex locked
memcpy'd
first: 1
```

Success.

#### Case 2

Doing this with the video file is different.  To recreate, uncomment the `VideoCapture` and `cap >> frame` lines and comment the `imread` line in the MWE.  The output when running is:

```
g++ test.cpp -Wall -g -O3 -L/opt/vc/lib/ -lpthread `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -I/opt/vc/include/ -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux -o frame_extractor
frame dimensions: 1920 x 1080 x 3 = 6220800
frame_fd: 10
buf size: 1
mutex locked
Bus error
```

Failure.

#### Case 3

Per suggestions made from [a Bus error question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242231/troubles-with-using-memcpy-with-mmap), I added an `ftruncate` line (commented in the MWE).  Uncommenting this line and running the program with the video file yields:

```
g++ test.cpp -Wall -g -O3 -L/opt/vc/lib/ -lpthread `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -I/opt/vc/include/ -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux -o frame_extractor
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:37:7: warning: unused variable ‘junk’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int junk = ftruncate(frame_fd, shmem_size);
       ^~~~
frame dimensions: 1920 x 1080 x 3 = 6220800
frame_fd: 10
buf size: 1
mutex locked
memcpy'd
first: 1
```

Success.

### Restating the question

Why did the video file require the file descriptor to be resized with `ftruncate`?  Why did the static frame not require it?  Is there a general way to know when the file descriptor needs to be resized?  Is there something inherent to the way `OpenCV` prepares the file that causes this?

### Errata

Compiled and run on Linux using `OpenCV` version: 3.4.1

Comment: Was the file newly created in both cases?  Does it fail in both cases if you explicitly add `O_TRUNC` to your `open` call?

Comment: Unrelated: Why do `#include <stdlib.h>  // for NULL` instead of using `nullptr` that doesn't require any includes?

Comment: @MilesBudnek Running the MWE with ``O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC`` in the ``open`` call causes case 1 to fail now.  Updating OP to make "cases" obvious.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's a holdover from the rest of the code not included in the MWE.  Much of the code isn't "native" C++, and is held together with shoestrings and GNUnicorns.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do please? Why do you have mutexes in single-threaded code? Have you checked the images are contiguous? Have you tried allocating, say, double memory to see if it works then and doing a binary search on how far wrong the size might be?

Comment: @MarkSetchell This MWE is taken from a larger code with multiple threads.  The end product will perform operations on frame_n while another fork fetches frame_n+1.  Hence, I am using ``memcpy`` to store a frame between different parts of the forked process.  The images are contiguous.

Comment: Have you tried adding `O_TRUNC` to the `open()` flags, or deleting the file before you run?

Comment: @MarkSetchell the ``O_TRUNC`` idea is addressed in the third comment here.  It causes case 1 to fail in addition to case 2.  Deleting the ``/tmp/file`` file has no apparent effect on operations.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why do you think OpenCV is doing something? It is surely not involved in `open()`, nor in `mmap()` nor in `memcpy()`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The only difference between case 1 and case 2 is the change in how the image is procured by ``OpenCV``.  The image ``Mat`` has the same dimensions (1920*1080*3).  Yet, case 2 generates a ``Bus error``.  Therefore, it must be preparing the ``Mat`` differently in some manner which causes the ``open``/``mmap``/``memcpy`` to behave in such a way that throws the error.

Comment: Are you passing the name of a `.MOV` file as parameter when testing video, or a camera number? Can you try just `memcpy(buf, frame.ptr(), shmem_size/2);`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Correct.  The first arg when called is either ``/path/to/image.png`` or ``/path/to/video.mp4`` depending on the example case being tested.  When you say to try ``memcpy(buf, frame.ptr(), shmem_size/2);`` do you mean to move that line outside of the ``mutex``?

Comment: While testing the MWE, the behavior changed.  Now case 1 is resulting in failure.  This makes more sense.  There is no diff in the code, so something may be acting strange on the computer side here.  Either I have a non-deterministic error or something was screwy on my end originally.  Question will be left up but not closed.

Comment: No, I didn't mean to move it outside mutex, I meant to just copy half the data to see if if is a sizing issue.

Comment: My next suggestion would be to remove the `-g` and `-o3` switches from the compilation command.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the suggestions and clarifications.  I will keep your tips in mind should I encounter something similar in the future.